# MVC EF6 Display images related to User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Related to my Previous Question

how we can display Images related to the User....who stored them.

we want to Display Images related to the PatientID

My Index Controller is

```
 // GET: Imagings
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        co.Values.Add("PID", id.ToString());
        co.Expires.AddMinutes(2.0);
        Response.SetCookie(co);
        pId = id;

       var res= db.Patients.Where(x => x.PatientID==id).ToList();
        foreach(var r in res)
                {
            ViewBag.PName = r.First_Name;
                }
        var imagings = db.Imagings.Include(i => i.ImageType).Include(i => i.Patient);
        return View(imagings.ToList());
    }
```

and my View is

```
@model IEnumerable<iSmileFinal.Models.Imaging>
@if (Model != null)
{
<div class="adsm-sec">
    @foreach (var vad in Model)
    {
        <div id="img">
            <div class="adsm-image-wraper">

                <img src="@Url.Content("~")UserImages/@vad.ImageUrl" alt="no photo" class="adsm-image"/>
            </div>
        </div>


        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vad.PatientID)

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vad.ImageType)

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vad.Comments)
    }
</div>
```

}

Thanks

Comment: When you store the image, you need to store it against a patientId and when you query , get for only the patient id you are dealing with.

Comment: i am already storing it against the user, how i can get list of related user, if the PatiendID = 4.......i want to display Images only for 4

Comment: Does your Imaging entity has a PatiendId property ?

Comment: yes......PatientID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ `Where` method  to filter images for only one patient

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   var imageList = db.Imagings.Where(a=>a.PatientID==id)
                          .Include(i => i.ImageType)
                          .Include(i => i.Patient).ToList();
   return View(imageList);
}
```

Assuming your `Imaging` entity has a `PatientID` property and you are storing the patient id when an image is stored to this table and you are passing a valid patient id to the this action method via `id` parameter.

Comment: var patientId =3 ;..............it should not be fixed to 3 only, .......when i click on "Imaging" in the actionlink i mention here...........@Html.ActionLink("Imaging", "Index", "Imagings", new { id = item.PatientID }, null)..............it get the ID of the patient from the list i "Clicked".............i want ....it display the images related to the Patient, i clicked.......Thanks

Comment: Works Great...............Thanks a Million sir.............may i ask you one more favor?

Comment: please see my new question

Comment: @Shyju.......i am waiting for your reply on my next question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277798/mvc-ef6-display-images-to-related-imagetype